# g++ being shown as installed even after apt-get installation

Tags: c++, g++, ubuntu-14.04

So when I first type g++ to check at the console, this is what happens:

```
arunirc@fisher:~$ g++
The program 'g++' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install g++
```

As suggested, I install g++ (did sudo apt-get update and -f before that).

```
arunirc@fisher:~$ sudo apt-get install g++
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
g++ is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 121 not upgraded.
```

But even after it shows that g++ is installed, this is what I get at the command line again:

```
arunirc@fisher:~$ g++
The program 'g++' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Please help! (I am on Ubuntu 14.04).

**EDIT 1**
(in response to comments)

`sudo update-alternatives --config g++` gives this output:

`update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for g++`

Comment: Try asking on http://askubuntu.com

Comment: Probably some other version of `g++` took over for the regular version and then was removed. Reinstalling the `g++` package will probably fix it.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/513349/how-can-i-know-that-i-have-g-installed-in-my-ubuntu

Comment: try to run `sudo update-alternatives --config g++`

Comment: @Slava included the output from running that command in the question EDIT    
@DavidSchwartz I tried reinstalling g++ using sudo apt-get, that did not work. were you referring to some different way of reinstalling `g++`?

Comment: Try installing `g++-5`

Comment: did you try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall g++`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
 locate /usr/bin/g++
```

{when this is out of date, use
      sudo updatedb 
}

My Ubuntu system currently shows

```
:~$ locate /usr/bin/g++
/usr/bin/g++
/usr/bin/g++-4.9
/usr/bin/g++-5
```

Next use

```
ls -lsa /usr/bin/g++
```

Mine shows

```
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5 Aug  1 14:32 /usr/bin/g++ -> g++-5
```

So, my g++ is simply a link to the latest installed g++.

Perhaps this link is either missing or installed incorrectly.

Try manually setting the link.

But before doing that, invoke it directly.

i.e.

```
/usr/bin/g++-5  --version
```

my system reports

```
g++-5 (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 5.2.1 20151010
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: I just tried setting the symlinks for g++ to be g++-4.8. That was the problem. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Look through Synaptic and see if you have anything related to g++ and purge it.